# Twitter widget for timeline view with o_auth request(Rate limiting API) using PHP

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using twitter widget for my site. [This](http://twitter.com/javascripts/widgets/widget.js) is the current js file I am using. I am facing the request time out issue for requests more than 150, which is due to the rate limiting API for **unauthenticated requests** as per the documentation.

Now I tried to go through the documentation to find how can I send an authenticated request i.e I will have to add an **o_auth parameter**, but was not successful. **How can I achive it?**

I also want to know if there exists a widget using which I can **change the color of the tweeted texts and the background** of the tweets.I want the user to have **custom settings** for the tweet box.Is their something present or I need to build it?

I am using **PHP** on server side.

Comment: Maybe try this widget: http://twitterforweb.com/ ?

Comment: @BartoszGrzybowski Any implementation example for this widget?This allows me to customize it for a user.I want the users to customize it from there end.Actually I am trying to integrate it with a CMS and it will act as a independent widget over there,so I need to handle the values dynamically,when user sets them through the console.Thanks for your help

Comment: @BartoszGrzybowski I did not find any files that I could use for development.Thanks

Comment: If You look closely in script there is settings option which u can change manually just implementing some basic script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://twitterforweb.com

If You look closely at embed code there is "settings" parameter which You can edit same as at the project site :)